# Smarty if statement with date?

Tags: smarty

If I have a smarty variable

```
{$test.date_created}
```

that displays a date in a smarty template, for example:

**02/2/2012**

On the smarty website, it says that you can display today's date with the following.

```
{$smarty.now|date_format:'%m/%d/%Y'}
```

How can I use it in an if statement to display a message when its 3 days old or more from today's date?

If its 3 days old or more, display "Old". If not, Display "New".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** to get the timestamp corresponding to three days ago, and then compare this to the date of your message. For example, assuming `$message` is your message record and `$message['date']` is the timestamp you have to check:

```
$isMessageOld = ($message['date'] <= strtotime('-3 days'));
$smarty->assign('isMessageOld', $isMessageOld);
```

And then, in your template:

```
{if $isMessageOld} ... {/if}
```

I'm not 100% sure, but you can also test it directly in Smarty. Assuming you have `$message` passed to Smarty:

```
{if $message.date <= strtotime('-3 days')} ... {/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check already passed date in smarty by using this $smarty.now

```
$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y%m%d"
```

Here is an example of cross the old(passed) date

```
<{foreach from=$meetings item=m}>
<{if $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y%m%d" <= $m.date|date_format:"%Y%m%d"}>
  <tr>
    <td><{counter}></td>
    <td><{$m.title}> on </td>
    <td><{$m.date}></td>
  </tr>
<{else}>
  <tr>
    <td><strike><{counter}></strike></td>
      <td><strike><{$m.title}> on </strike></td>
      <td><strike><{$m.date}></strike></td>
  </tr>
<{/if}>
<{/foreach}>
```

We need to create meeting list array in php and assign it in smarty

```
$meetings[0]['title'] = "Speech on Gandhi Janyanti";
$meetings[0]['date'] = "2-Oct-2011";
$meetings[1]['title'] = "Meet friend";
$meetings[1]['date'] = "10-Oct-2013";
$meetings[2]['title'] = "Goto USA";
$meetings[2]['date'] = "22-Oct-2013";
$meetings[3]['title'] = "Speech on Gandhi Janyanti";
$meetings[3]['date'] = "2-Oct-2014";
$meetings[4]['title'] = "Meeting with John";
$meetings[4]['date'] = "22-Oct-2014";
$meetings[5]['title'] = "Speech on Gandhi Janyanti";
$meetings[5]['date'] = "2-Oct-2015";
$meetings[6]['title'] = "Meeting with Uncle";
$meetings[6]['date'] = "22-Oct-2015";

$theme->assign("meetings",$meetings);
echo $theme->fetch("index.tpl");
```

Comment: Nice but you would be better of doing: `{if $smarty.now <= $m.date.value|@strtotime}`